# Spring Boot application deployed on Heroku still crashing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku

i deployed my Spring app on Heroku but it crashes every time. Application works fine on localhost and also seems to correctly starting on Heroku but after one minute it crashes. I can't even open it because i've got timeout. I attached end of the logs:

```
2020-04-09T15:29:42.942785+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-09 15:29:42.942  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-09T15:29:42.945506+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-09 15:29:42.945  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.a.a.backend.BackendApplication  : Started BackendApplication in 15.604 seconds (JVM running for 17.531)
2020-04-09T15:30:53.816851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

There is nothing more in logs. What can i check?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not binding your tomcat to the correct port. You need to bind to the Heroku provided `$PORT` env variable. Heroku has an article about this, that also covers Tomcat: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications